# Remove trailing brackets in a string

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, str-replace, gsub

I'm trying to trim trailing square brackets, inner quotes and slashes in a list of R strings, preferably using `dplyr`.

Sample data:

```r
df <- c("['Mamie Smith']", "[\"Screamin' Jay Hawkins\"]")
```

Expected result:

```
"Mamie Smith", "Screamin' Jay Hawkins"
```

What I have tried:

```r
gsub("[[]]", "", df) # Throws error
```

```
df %>%
  str_replace("[[]]", "") # Also throws error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another, relatively easy, regex solution is this:

```
data.frame(df) %>%
  mutate(df = gsub("\\[\\W+|\\W+\\]", "", df))
                     df
1           Mamie Smith
2 Screamin' Jay Hawkins
```

Here we remove any non-alphanumeric character (`\\W+`) occurring one or more times on the condition that it be preceded OR (`|`)  followed by a square bracket.

Alternatively, to borrow from @TaerJae but greatly simplified:

```
library(stringr)
data.frame(df) %>%
  mutate(df = str_extract(df, '\\w.*\\w'))
```

Here we simply focus on the alphanumeric characters (`\\w`) on either side of the string, while allowing for any characters (`.*`) to occur in-between them thus capturing, for example, the apostrophe in `Screamin'`and the whitespaces.

Answer (score 3):

In base R we can make use of `trimws` function:

if we are not interested in the non word parts:

```
trimws(df, whitespace = "\\W+")
[1] "Mamie Smith"           "Screamin' Jay Hawkins"
```

But if we are only interested in deleting squarebrackets and quotes while leaving other punctuatons, spaces etc then:

```
trimws(df, whitespace = "[\\]\\[\"']+")
[1] "Mamie Smith"           "Screamin' Jay Hawkins"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Base R:**

```
sapply(regmatches(df, regexec('(\\w.*)(.*\\w)', df)), "[", 1)

[1] "Mamie Smith"           "Screamin' Jay Hawkins"
```

**OR**

We could use `str_extract` from `stringr` package with this regex:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract(df, '(\\w.*)(.*\\w)')

[1] "Mamie Smith"           "Screamin' Jay Hawkins"
```

Answer (score 2):

To pair up the square brackets with the accompanying type of quote, you can use:

```
\[(["'])(.*?)\1]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(["'])` Capture **group 1**, capture either `"` or `'`
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 2**, match as least as possible characters
- `\1` Backreference to group 1 to match the same type of quote
- `]` Match `]`

In the replacement use the value of capture group 2 using `\\2`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fAWsMn/1) | [R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyVNwUZXIVlDKVrdNzE3M1UhODezJEM9VklHQSk6Rik4uSgVKJynruCVWKngkVienZlXHKMUq6TJlV5cmqShFBMTrQFUpx6rqaGnZa8ZE2MI1hoTYwSkUtI0//8HAA)

```
df <- c("['Mamie Smith']", "[\"Screamin' Jay Hawkins\"]")
gsub("\\[([\"'])(.*?)\\1]", "\\2", df)
```

Output

```
[1] "Mamie Smith"           "Screamin' Jay Hawkins"
```

Comment: Thanks so much.

Mind explaining what "\\2" does here.

Comment: @afrologicinsect That is a backreference to the value of capture group 2, I have update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

since `[`, `]` and `"` are special characters you need to 'escape' with a double backslash `\\`

here's some alt code:

```
gsub('\\"|\\[|\\]', "", df)
```

Comment: Your output is `"'Mamie Smith'"` and `"Screamin' Jay Hawkins"`, where the single quotes remain.

Answer (score 0):

When looking for `]` inside `[]` it need to be on first place `[]]` or esacpe it on other places. Quotes which are used for the string need to be escaped when used inside `"[\"]"` or `'["]'`. In the example string are no slashes (here they are only escaping `"`).

```
gsub("[]['\"]", "", df)
#[1] "Mamie Smith"          "Screamin Jay Hawkins"
```

Another option, avoiding escaping `"` or `'` is to use raw character constants `r"(...)"`.

```
gsub(r"([]["'])", "", df)
#[1] "Mamie Smith"          "Screamin Jay Hawkins"
```

To limit the search to the borders `^` (begin) and `$` (end) need to be given.

```
gsub("^[]['\"]*|[]['\"]*$", "", df)
#[1] "Mamie Smith"           "Screamin' Jay Hawkins"
```

or `trimws` could be used.

```
trimws(df, "both", "[]['\"]")
#[1] "Mamie Smith"           "Screamin' Jay Hawkins"
```